# combine 2 ienumerable with distinct type (one to many)

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have to list like this :

```
IEnumerable<Entities.Article> articlelist;
IEnumerable<Entities.MeasureUnit> measureList
```

I want to combine the lists into one. Combining an article with all the units of measurement in a communion list taking only the name article, ID unit of measure, Name unit of measure.

You could do two loops for each item in a list, but I would like to know if there is a way to make it simpler with linq.

Foreach Example:

```
            foreach(Entities.Article article in articlelist.ToList())
            {
                foreach(Entities.MeasureUnit measureUnit in measureList.ToList())
                {

                    searchList.Add(new Models.SearchItem() { IDItem = measureUnit.IDMeasureUnit, PrincipalProperty = article.Description, SecondaryProperty = measureUnit.Description });

                }
            }
```

Comment: Consider posting on https://es.stackoverflow.com/ , or translate the question to eng

Comment: english please ?

Comment: ok sorry i try to translate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to build this cartesian product:

```
IEnumeable<Models.SearchItem> searchItems = articlelist
   .SelectMany(article => measureList, (a, m) 
      => new Models.SearchItem() { IDItem = m.IDMeasureUnit, PrincipalProperty = a.Description, SecondaryProperty = m.Description });
```